# How to implement client-server udp multicast in one program?

Tags: c++, udp, client-server, multicast

I have written a server and a client both as separate apps. They communicate through UDP Multicast (becouse I need that everyone who joins the group can read & write messages). Now I have two windows, but my aim is to create one simple chat program, but I don't know how to listen and send at the same time. Do I need to create 2 sockets? Or can I use just one? I've even tried to merge both apps in one, but I didn't succeeded (I know, I know.. but I was kinda desperate).

I've searched google for a tut, but didn't succeeded.

I'm using c++.

Comment: What's wrong with having a server with multiple connected clients that send messages to each other?  This is a bit too vague for a good answer without knowing more about what you have currently implemented and what your requirements are ...

Comment: I have a LAN with 10-12 clients and we just need a simple chat program, we don't need no servers, just a simple app. I hope I'm clear enough. Sorry for my language, not a native speaker so perhaps thats why my post is so misterious :)

Comment: Well to state the obvious you could just use a free program like Skype but I was referring to coding requirements for your project and details about what you have implemented currently.  The simplest chat system you could implement would be browser based using HTML posts but since you already have multicast you may be able to combine listeners with broadcasts in one program.  Here's something for simple inspiration: http://ntrg.cs.tcd.ie/undergrad/4ba2/multicast/antony/example.html

Comment: Yes, thats what Im up to - to combine listeners and broadcasts. Thanks for the link!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use one or two sockets, it all depends on whether you wish to bind to a particular network adapter and whether you wish to use unicast & broadcast packets.  It is often easier to manage one for sending and one for receiving.

To listen to sent multicast packets on the same host check the `IP_MULTICAST_LOOP` socket option, noting it applies differently on Windows to Unix.